# Has anyone gotten the javascript msProtocols property to work in IE10?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

My web application needs to detect whether our desktop application is installed on the user's PC.  (This application is launched from the web app via custom application protocol.)  We currently have a "hack-ish" method working, but it is broken in IE10.  Doing some research, I came upon this article.

[Understanding Protocols](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/14/url-protocols-application-protocols-and-asynchronous-pluggable-protocols-oh-my.aspx)

Towards the bottom, it explains how on Windows 8 & IE10, you can now detect for a specific application protocol handler using javascript.  More specifics can be found at this site: [msProtocols property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  According to the example, I should be able to do something like this:

```
if (navigator.msProtocols["myProtocol"]) {
    location.href = "myProtocol://<Some path under the myProtocol protocol>";
} else {
    // Fallback code for when the "myProtocol" protocol doesn’t exist.
}
```

I've tried to get this working, but failed.  Even using the debugger, and looking at the navigator object, there is no msProtocols property.

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: Figured out my own problem.  Should have been one of the first things I checked, but my Browser Mode & Document Mode were incorrectly set.  Once I set them to IE10 - Standards, everything worked beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you're testing something with Internet Explorer 8+, make sure your Browser Mode and Document Mode are set to the appropriate states. For instance, having a Browser Mode less than Internet Explorer 10, and a Document Mode other than Standards, will prevent you from gaining access to the `msProtocols` member.

Check these settings by pressing F12 to reveal the Developer Tools. In the bigger picture of whether you should be using this member or not, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states:

> **This member is not supported and should not be used.** Determines if a specified protocol has an associated protocol handler.

Whether you find success in using this member or not, I would avoid it and find an alternative.